# How to completely ignore whitespaces in csv with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to make a .csv file in a format that is both minimally human-readable and also easily pandas-readable. That means columns should be neatly separated so you can easily identify to which column each value belongs. Problem is, filling it up with whitespaces has some cut-downs in pandas functionality. So far what I've got is

```
work    ,roughness  ,unstab ,corr_c_w   ,u_star ,c_star
us      ,True       ,True   ,-0.39      ,0.35   ,-.99
wang    ,False      ,       ,-0.5       ,       ,
cheng   ,           ,True   ,           ,       ,
watanabe,           ,       ,           ,0.15   ,-.80
```

If I take out all the whitespaces on the above .csv and read it directly with `pd.read_csv` it works perfectly. The first two columns are booleans and the others are floats. However, it is not human-readable at all without the whitespaces. When I read the above .csv with

```
pd.read_csv('bibrev.csv', index_col=0)
```

it doesn't work because all the columns and considered string that include, obviously, the whitespaces. When I use

```
pd.read_csv('bibrev.csv', index_col=0, skipinitialspace=True)
```

then it kind of works, because floats are read as floats and missing values are read as `NaN`s, which is a big improvement. However, the column names and boolean columns are still strings with whitespaces.

Any method of reading that .csv directly with pandas? Or maybe chance the csv format a bit and still have a clean-read with a human-readable .csv?

PS.: I am trying to avoid reading everything with python as a string, replacing whitespaces and then feeding it to pandas and also trying to avoid defining some functions and passing it to pandas through the `converters` keyword.

Comment: I hope my code help you, I posted it [in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960024/13065379)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd

def booleator(col):
    if str(col).lower() in ['true', 'yes']:
        return True
    #elif str(col).lower() == "false":
    #    return False
    else:
        return False

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\s*,\s*', index_col=0,
                 converters={'roughness': booleator, 'unstab': booleator},
                 engine='python')
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
         roughness unstab  corr_c_w  u_star  c_star
work
us            True   True     -0.39    0.35   -0.99
wang         False  False     -0.50     NaN     NaN
cheng        False   True       NaN     NaN     NaN
watanabe     False  False       NaN    0.15   -0.80
roughness       bool
unstab          bool
corr_c_w     float64
u_star       float64
c_star       float64
dtype: object
```

This version also takes care of booleans - all NaN's will be converted to False, otherwise Pandas will promote dtype to Object (see details in my comment)...

Comment: I think it should actually be `pd.read_csv('bibrev.csv', sep='\s+,', index_col=0)` right? But it worked really well except that the boolean column is a string, and not bool.

Comment: @TomCho, "When introducing NAs into an existing Series or DataFrame via reindex or some other means, boolean and integer types will be promoted to a different dtype in order to store the NAs" - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html. So you would have first get rid of NaNs...

Comment: Actually your new answer is exactly what I need. That's regex, right?

Comment: @TomCho, yes it's regex, which should work whether you have spaces or not