# Remove '\t' in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in a csv fomat

```
     id,    weight, height, wc, hc, sex,    birthdate
    187,     55.6,   154,   92, 89,   F,     21/11/1947
```

When I loaded it to to pandas dataframe, the row looks like this for sex and birthdate

```
\tF \t21/11/1947
```

How do I remove `\t` in front of the string value? I also need to compute the age of the person given from format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

*it seems that the csv file really has some white space or tabbed thats why \t was appearing. thanks for everyone who has given their answer

Comment: Are you using [`.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)?

Comment: If you are you using `read_csv()`, you can probably use [`sep='\s*,\s*'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35781099/5858851).

Comment: those are better options, but for completeness, you should be able to do something like `df['birthdate'] = df.birthrate.str.strip()` to do vectorized string operations....