# Stripping whtiespace from a dask dataframe colunn

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am relatively new to Dask and have a large file 12GB that I wish to process. This file was imported from a SQL BCP file that I want to wrangle with Dask prior to uploading to sql. As part of this, I need to remove some proceeding whitespace e.g. '     SQL Tutorial’ changed to 'SQL Tutorial'. I would do this using pandas as follows:

```
df_train['colum1'] = pd.core.strings.str_strip(df_train['column1'])
```

dask doesn't seem to have this feature as I get the error

> AttributeError: module 'dask.dataframe.core' has no attribute
> 'strings'

Is there a memory-efficient way to do this using dask?

Comment: How working `df_train['colum1'] = df_train['column1'].str.strip()` ?

Comment: maybe i'm wrong but i thought that doesn't always work and can have leave NaN values.

Comment: It should working

Comment: it's working an no NaN Values.

Comment: Not sure if working in dask, is possible use `sep='\s*,\s*'` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35781099) ?

Comment: It's tab-delimited so I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long searching I find it in [dask API](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=Series.str#dask.dataframe.Series.str):

> **str**
> Namespace for string methods

So you can use:

```
df_train['colum1'] = df_train['column1'].str.strip()
```